# Spark on embedded mode - user/hive/warehouse not found

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm using Apache Spark in embedded local mode. I have all the dependencies included in my *pom.xml* and in the same version (spark-core_2.10, spark-sql_2.10, and spark-hive_2.10).

I just want to run a HiveQL query to create a table (stored as Parquet).

Running the following (rather simple) code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkSQL").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g");
        JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        HiveContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(ctx.sc());

        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (id int, name string) STORED AS PARQUET";
        sqlContext.sql(createQuery);
    }
}
```

...is returning the following exception:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/test is not a directory or unable to create one)
```

I can see the `metastore_db` folder created in the root of the project.

I searched around and the solutions found didn't help --most of them were not for the embedded mode.

- One solution was to check the permissions, I'm using the same user for everything.
- Another solution was to create the folder manually in HDFS, I did and I can navigate to /user/hive/warehouse/test.
- One solution was to set manually the metastore by adding:     `sqlContext.sql("SET hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse");`.

I'm running out of ideas right now, can someone provide any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're running in local embedded mode, HDFS is not being considered. This is why the error says `file:/user/hive/warehouse/test` rather than `hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/test`. It expects `/user/hive/warehouse/test` to exist on your local machine. Try creating it locally.

Comment: I have tried the same , created a hive table but it got created in my local system instead on Hive machine .

objHiveContext.sql("create table yahoo_orc_table (date STRING, open_price FLOAT, high_price FLOAT, low_price FLOAT, close_price FLOAT, volume INT, adj_price FLOAT) stored as orc")

How to change the mode?

I tried with below
objHiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://myServerIP:portNumber/apps/hive/warehouse")

Answer (score 6):

Just in case this helps anybody else in the future, I'm attempting to write some unit tests against Spark code that uses a HiveContext. I've found that in order to change the path where the files are written for the tests, I needed to call hiveContext.setConf. I also tried the same approach as OP, performing a `SET` query, but that didn't work. The following seems to work!

```
hive.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", 
  "file:///custom/path/to/hive/warehouse")
```

And just to make this a tad more useful, I specifically set this path to a location my code had access to:

```
hive.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", 
  getClass.getResource(".").toString)
```

With this, I've been able to write unit tests against my code making use of hive queries and the Spark API.

Comment: I found that `saveAsTable()` without an explicitly provided path ignores this setting and uses the default from `hive-site.xml`.