# Hive configuration for Spark integration tests

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, scalatest

I am looking for a way to configure Hive for Spark SQL integration testing such that tables are written either in a temporary directory or somewhere under the test root. My investigation suggests that this requires setting both `fs.defaultFS` and `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` before `HiveContext` is created.

Just setting the latter, as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248723/622495) is not working on Spark 1.6.1.

```
val sqlc = new HiveContext(sparkContext)
sqlc.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", hiveWarehouseDir)
```

The table metadata goes in the right place but the written files go to /user/hive/warehouse.

If a dataframe is saved without an explicit path, e.g.,

```
df.write.saveAsTable("tbl")
```

the location to write files to is determined via a call to `HiveMetastoreCatalog.hiveDefaultTableFilePath`, which uses the `location` of the default database, which seems to be cached during the `HiveContext` construction, thus setting `fs.defaultFS` after `HiveContext` construction has no effect.

As an aside, but very relevant for integration testing, this also means that `DROP TABLE tbl` only removes the table metadata but leaves the table files, which wreaks havoc with expectations. This is a known problem--see [here](http://markmail.org/message/56ub3vgg5sck2j43) & [here](http://markmail.org/message/56ub3vgg5sck2j43)--and the solution may be to ensure that `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` == `fs.defaultFS` + `user/hive/warehouse`.

In short, how can configuration properties such as `fs.defaultFS` and `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` be set programmatically *before* the `HiveContext` constructor runs?

Comment: You mention in the 2nd paragraph, thatit's not working on Spark 1.6.1., are you implying it works on other versions?

Comment: I assumed it is working on some other version because of @steven-bakhtiari's answer I link to, which claims so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark 2.0 you can set "spark.sql.warehouse.dir" on the SparkSession's builder, before creating a SparkSession. It should propagate correctly.

For Spark 1.6, I think your best bet might be to programmatically create a hite-site.xml.

Answer (score 2):

The [`spark-testing-base`](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base) library has a [`TestHiveContext`](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/55294c5d0e09082d244772de9cf11c4f7a7389a6/src/main/pre-2.0/scala/com/holdenkarau/spark/testing/TestHiveContext.scala#L28-L34) configured as part of the setup for [`DataFrameSuiteBaseLike`](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/4d38a93ca37eaa6caee1b16cf2091a6f27e0cb28/src/main/pre-2.0/scala/com/holdenkarau/spark/testing/DataFrameSuiteBase.scala#L54-L78). Even if you're unable to use `scala-testing-base` directly for some reason, you can see how they make the configuration work.